# Comparison Theory: Test for convergence

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, convergence-divergence

Given this integral: $$ \int_1^\infty {x+1\over\sqrt{x^4-x}}dx $$

Determine whether this integral is convergent or divergent.

Comment: I know it will be divergent, therefore I must compare it to a function that is smaller than the given integral for all x values AND is also divergent. What is an integral that satisfies this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint :

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4-x}}dx \geq \int_1^\infty \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^4}}dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{x+1}{x^2}dx$$
$$=\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{x^2}dx +\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx +\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}dx$$

Make sure to justify why each step is correct!

Answer (score 1):

It's straightforward if you resort to the inequality

$$\frac{1}{x}\le{x+1\over\sqrt{x^4-x}}$$